# How to disable Google’s “Video Call” default in Calendar Api?

Tags: java, calendar, google-api, call, google-calendar-api

I'm implementing a software that creates an event in a calendar, but when I create it, Google adds a hangout (video call) link by default.
Thats make the event a bit confusing.

I know that you can eliminate this by going to the user advanced options and untick the option, but I cant access it. 
I'm using java and **OAuth** 2.0 to get the token with the permissions, and calendar **v3 api** to create the event.

Is there anyway you can eliminate this hangout link throughout code?

In the documentation I've found:
`myEntry.setHangoutLink(null);`
but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

**Edited 2018-09-19**

You can remove the Hangout from a Google Calendar event by making an [`Events.patch`](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/patch) request, ensuring you set the query parameter `conferenceDataVersion` to `1` and with a body that sets `conferenceData` to `null`. For example:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events/{EVENT_ID}
     ?conferenceDataVersion=1
Authorization: Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}

{
 "conferenceData": null
}
```

Comment: Well, I have tried to set a "default" web page in the hangout link, but it changes to the actual link. Thanks for the answer, I guess I have to wait.

Comment: Sooner rather than later, please. I really don't want that Hangouts link there.

Comment: I'm also interested if this functionality has been added via the API.

Comment: Has any progress been made with at least allowing one to create an event without a hangout link? I find that it causing more confusion for our users, especially in situations where it's an in-person meeting or a phone call. SO for best user experience we really need this functionality.

Comment: Eric, any update on whether it is possible to remove (in my case) the Google Hangouts link from calendar events via the Calendar API?  I've got many thousands of events going back several years that had the Hangout URL/cruft added, and while I've disabled automatic creation of new events, it doesn't fix the old events, and removing them all by hand is impractical.  I was looking to modify the "Bulk Edit Calendar Events" script (can't insert URL here, Google it :-) to remove them, but I can't find an API to do it.  Is this stored as a "tag" or other attribute that could be modified?

Comment: It is possible now! Updated with the latest information.

Answer (score 5):

If anyone is still looking for the solution. Here is an example of how we have done it using npm module googleapis.

This is done during 'insert' and not during 'patch'. Please note that  'conferenceData' is null and conferenceDataVersion is set to 1.

```
var event = {
    'summary': 'some summary data here',
    'location': 'some location',
    'description': 'add your description',
    'start': {
        'dateTime': 'add your start time here',
    },
    'end': {
        'dateTime': 'add your end time here',
    },
    'attendees': [{
            'email': 'attendee1@email.com'
        }
    ],
    'reminders': {
        'useDefault': true
    },
    'conferenceData' : null
};

calendar.events.insert({
    auth: oauth2Client,
    calendarId: 'primary',
    conferenceDataVersion: 1,
    resource: event,
    sendNotifications: false,
    email: 'youremail@emailprovider.com'

}, function (err, event) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
    console.log(event)
});
```

Comment: thanks! I'll also leave it here just for future reference: "conferenceDataVersion : Version number of conference data supported by the API client. Version 0 assumes no conference data support and ignores conference data in the event's body. Version 1 enables support for copying of ConferenceData as well as for creating new conferences using the createRequest field of conferenceData. The default is 0."