# How do I add a video call to a calendar event? (G Suite)

Tags: google-calendar-api

This is related to events created for accounts in a "G Suite" organization. In the API docs I can only find a field "hangoutLink", which is read-only. Is there any way to add a video call via the API?

Comment: There is currently no way to do that via the API afaik. The G suite organization can choose to add links to all the meetings and then these links would also get populated.

Answer (score 0):

I actually tried creating an event in [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) and `hangoutLink` property is given in the response body. As discussed in [Events resource](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource), it is an absolute link to the Google+ hangout associated with this event. Attendees who wish to join the video call need only to visit the link and you can also verify it from the event which you have created.

For helpful insights, you may want to visit these links:

- [Google Calendar Automatically Adds Video Calls](https://swampsidestudio.com/google-calendar-automatically-adds-video-calls/)
- [Hangouts video calls in Google Calendar](https://support.google.com/a/answer/4362302?hl=en)
- [How to disable Google’s “Video Call” default in Calendar Api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26711435/how-to-disable-google-s-video-call-default-in-calendar-api)